# Background scale so part of image fills div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an image (let's say it's `100px by 100px`). I want to use the image as the background of a div, however I only want the first `50px by 50px` to be visible (the other three 'corners' will be used as other backgrounds). I also want to scale the image so that the piece of the image I specify fills the div. For example, if my div is `150px by 150px`, i'd want to crop by image to `50px by 50px`, and then render it as `150px by 150px`.

---

I can render the image in the background like so (using `react`): `<div style={{width: '5vh', height: '5vh', background: 'url(./image) 0px 0px'}}></div>`, **however this does not scale the image back to the size I want it.** How can I achieve the effect I desire?

---

Is it described in the image below, where the black square is the div, and the red is the content I want visible in the background, while the blue & red are the entire source image.

### [image]

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779722/showing-only-a-part-of-image-in-div-using-css), however that answer is several years old and does not rescale the image either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To divide the image in four you need to double it's dimensions (in relation to the containing div)

```
background-size:200% 200% ;
```

Then you use background-position to choose the portion you need:

```css
div{
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-9.jpg');
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-size:200% 200% ;
  background-position: 0 0; // is top-left
  /* background-position: 100%  100%// is bottom-right */
}
```

```html
<div>
```

PS: reactwise you need to camelCase the hyphened properties( ex: `background-size` will become `backgroundSize` )